What is the complexity of this nested loop, where both loop variables double each iteration?
What would the time complexity of the following code snippet?
for (i = 1; i <= n; i *= 2) 
{ 
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j *= 2) 
    {
        // SOME TASKS 
    } 
}

I consulted some GenAIs, which indicate that it would be O((logn)^2). But is that correct? GPT and Claude gave me the following answers:

We can express the overall time complexity as: ∑i=1,2,4,…,n O(log⁡i)
This sum roughly equals: O(log⁡1+log⁡2+log⁡4+⋯+log⁡n)
Using the properties of logarithms, we can simplify this to: O(log⁡n⋅log⁡n)=O((log⁡n)^2)
Final Answer
The total time complexity for this code is: O((log⁡n)^2)

I followed the same strategy mentioned in a similar Q&A on Stack Overflow, but I didn't manage to use those ideas on this variant.

The outer loop runs log(n) times because the loop variable i is multiplied by 2 for each iteration. The inner loop also runs log(i) times, which is also log(n) times. Therefore, the overall time complexity is O(log(n) * log(n)) = O(log^2(n)). See running time of (log base 2 (n) * log base 2 (n))

You cannot know the complexity if the complexity of "SOME TASKS" is not provided.

Assuming that "SOME TASKS" has a constant time complexity, the complexity is indeed O( log2 ). We can analyse it as follows:
The values of  will be powers of 2, starting with 20, 21, 22, 23, ... not exceeding , i.e. the final value of  is 2⌊log2⌋ (the greatest power of 2 that is not more than ).
The number of iterations of the inner loop are log2, where  takes the above listed values. That makes the total number of executions of "SOME TASKS":
      log220 + log221 + log222 + ... +  log22⌊log2⌋
...which is:
      0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + ⌊log2⌋
This is a triangular number, and so we get a complexity that is in the order of the square of the final term:
      O( log2 )
